# Not finding a good regex pattern to substitute the strings in a correct order(python)

Tags: python, regex, string, list, python-re

I have a list of column names that are in string format like below:

```
lst = ["plug", "[plug+wallet]", "(wallet-phone)"]
```

Now I want to add `df[]` with `" ' "` to each column name using regex and I did it which does that when the list has `(wallet-phone)` this kind of string it gives an output like this `df[('wallet']-df['phone')]`. How do I get like this `(df['wallet']-df['phone']),` Is my pattern wrong. Please refer it below:

```
import re
lst = ["plug", "[plug+wallet]", "(wallet-phone)"]
x=[]
y=[]
for l in lst: 
    x.append(re.sub(r"([^+\-*\/'\d]+)", r"'\1'", l))
    for f in x:    
        y.append(re.sub(r"('[^+\-*\/'\d]+')", r'df[\1]',f))

print(x)
print(y)
```

gives:

```
x:["'plug'", "'[plug'+'wallet]'", "'(wallet'-'phone)'"]
y:["df['plug']", "df['[plug']+df['wallet]']", "df['(wallet']-df['phone)']"]
```

Is the pattern wrong?
Expected output:

```
x:["'plug'", "['plug'+'wallet']", "('wallet'-'phone')"]
y:["df['plug']", "[df['plug']+df['wallet']]", "(df['wallet']-df['phone'])"]
```

I also tried `([^+\-*\/()[]'\d]+)` this pattern but it isn't avoiding `() or []`

Comment: Maybe try like `([^+\-*\/\(\)\[\]'\d]+)`?

Comment: @YashvanderBamel Yes! it did Thanks a ton :) :)

Comment: I wonder what your end goal is. I have a feeling you are trying to solve a problem with regular expressions that is best done another way.

Comment: @wbg I just want to calculate data frame column records. To do that I can only pass the names of the column but I can't send df['col1']+df['col']. TO add that I am using regex and then calculate the records in it.

Comment: @Toi I'm sure there is a way without hacking the columns names. I suggest starting another SO question with the Pandas tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to locate words and enclose them in the dictionary reference:

```
import re
lst = ["plug", "[plug+wallet]", "(wallet-phone)"]

z = [re.sub(r"(\w+)",r"df['\1']",w) for w in lst]

print(z)
["df['plug']", "[df['plug']+df['wallet']]", "(df['wallet']-df['phone'])"]
```